# Remote Installing OS X 10.5 on a PowerBook G4

Tags: remote, osx-leopard, g4, powerbook

I recently acquired a PowerBook G4 (always loved the PPC architecture over Intel when it comes to Apple), currently it has OS X 10.4 installed.

Unfortunately I can't find the original 10.5 install disc I had, though I made an ISO of it some time ago, which I've now burnt to a DVD-R DL disc (the SuperDrive is a DVD-R only iirc).  This disc keeps being ejected by the PowerBook G4 (reads other discs just fine, except one).

So I've been pondering doing a remote install, however the instructions I've seen are for MacBooks - I have DVD or CD Sharing installed, but the part in the instructions (http://guides.macrumors.com/Complete_Steps_to_Perform_a_Clean_OS_X_Reinstall_on_Your_MacBook_Air#Using_Remote_Install) about the 'Install Assistant', I don't get such a thing - only the BootCamp Installer.

So my question is: How do I go about doing a remote install on this PowerBook G4? Or is there another alternative, without forking out on a new drive?

Comment: On a further note, I purchased a slimline external DVD+/-RW drive today, the disc reads fine on my windows machine, but won't read at all on the PowerBook (through the external drive).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem installing OSX leopard to an iMac G4 (host). to solve the problem I put the OSX leopard disc in the optical drive of my power mac G5 (target). I then restarted the G5 in target disc mode by holding down the T key during startup. You will know this worked if you see the firewire symbol on your target computer. I then connected a firewire cable between the two computers. I powered on the G4 while holding down the option key. This will display all of the possible startup discs. I chose the optical drive of the G5 as the startup disc for the G4. The G4 then began the OSX leopard install using the disc in the optical drive bay of the G5.